# Problems in Installing a CFD software, OpenFOAM-4.0, on CentOS SL RHEL

Tags: root, paraview, openfoam

I am an MPhil student doing CFD, and I have some problems when I am trying to install OpenFOAM-4.0 on the computer cluster managed by the university. I followed the instructions given by the following website:
https://openfoamwiki.net/index.php/Installation/Linux/OpenFOAM-4.0/CentOS_SL_RHEL

The main problem is, I do not have the permission to access the cluster as root, in other words, I cannot install the libraries by simply typing the commands like “sudo”. Is it possible to install the libraries, OpenFOAM itself and Third-party software, e.g. Paraview, in my home directory?

Besides, is it possible to get rid of the “root” problem if I do not install the Third-party software like Paraview, or if I install OpenFOAM® v1606+ ?? Or can I just install the OpenFOAM on the cluster, and do post-processing using Paraview on my desktop computer?

I found some software, for instance, easybuild and juju, who claim that they can get rid of the “root” problem, but I am not sure if they are really useful.

FYI, the general information of the computer cluster:

1. Operating System: CentOS 6.6 64-bit
2. Architecture: x86_64
3. Open MPI: v2.0.0
4. Python: v2.6.6
5. bison (GNU Bison): v2.4.1
6. flex: v2.5.35
7. GCC (GNU Compiler Collection): v4.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can install all applications into your home folder without root access. For this, you need to download the source code and compile it in your account in the cluster. Basically, for any application, you can follow the steps given in the link below:

[The details for installing without root access](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42583)

For ParaView, please follow this link:

[ParaView installation without root access](https://openfoamwiki.net/index.php/Installation/Linux/OpenFOAM-4.0/CentOS_SL_RHEL)